# How to do calculation to change pages in PaginationComponent

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Here in my code I have the calculation about getting pagination, `pageCount`, `pageSize` and the `offset`indicates the starting position of the query in relation to the complete set of unpaginated items. I need help and who could help me with the `handlePageChange` to change pages ?

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
    offset: number,
    pageSize: number,
    count: number,
    onPageChange: (event: SyntheticInputEvent<*>) => void,
    onPageSizeChange: (number) => void,
}

class Pagination extends React.Component<Props> {
    static defaultProps = {
        pageSize: 10,
    };

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.pageInput = React.createRef();
    }

    getPagination = () => {
        const { count, pageSize, offset } = this.props;

        return {
            pages: Math.ceil((count / pageSize) || 1),
            currentPage: ((offset / pageSize) || 0) + 1,
        };
    };

    handlePageSizeChange = (e: SyntheticInputEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (!e.target.value || e.target.value < 1) {
            e.target.value = 1;
        }
        console.log(e.target.value);
        this.props.onPageSizeChange(e.target.value);
    };

    handlePageChange = (e: SyntheticInputEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { pages } = this.getPagination();

        if (!e.target.value || e.target.value < 1) {
            e.target.value = 1;
        }

        if (e.target.value >= pages) {
            e.target.value = pages;
        }

        this.props.onPageChange(e.target.value - 1);
    };

    handleNextPageChange = (event: SyntheticMouseEvent<HTMLButtonElementT>) => {
        const newPage = this.getPagination().currentPage;

        this.pageInput.current.value = newPage + 1;

        this.props.onPageChange(newPage);
    };

    handlePrevPageChange = (event: SyntheticMouseEvent<HTMLButtonElementT>) => {
        const newPage = this.getPagination().currentPage - 2;

        this.pageInput.current.value = newPage + 1;

        this.props.onPageChange(newPage);
    };

    render(): React.ReactNode {
        const { pageSize } = this.props;
        const page = this.getPagination();

        return (
            <Box direction="row" justify="end">
                <Box direction="row">
                    <Box pad="small">
                        <Button
                            disabled={page.currentPage === 1}
                            icon={<Previous align="center" />}
                            plain={false}
                            onClick={this.handlePrevPageChange}
                            size="small"
                        />
                    </Box>
                    <Box
                        direction="row"
                        gap="small"
                        align="center"
                    >
                        <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}> Page </span>
                        <TextInput
                            type="number"
                            min="1"
                            defaultValue={page.currentPage}
                            onBlur={this.handlePageChange}
                            ref={this.pageInput}
                            size="small"
                        />

                        <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}> of </span>
                        <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                            {' '}
                            {page.pages}
                            {' '}
                        </span>

                        <TextInput
                            type="number"
                            min="1"
                            defaultValue={pageSize}
                            onBlur={this.handlePageSizeChange}
                            size="small"
                        />
                        <span
                            direction="row"
                            justify="end"
                            style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                        >
                            Rows
                        </span>
                    </Box>
                    <Box pad="small">
                        <Button
                            disabled={page.currentPage >= page.pages}
                            icon={<Next />}
                            plain={false}
                            onClick={this.handleNextPageChange}
                            size="small"
                        />
                    </Box>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        );
    }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: what are you getting in the `event.target.value`

Comment: In html (Grommet) there is an input text. The current value goes into this `e.target.value`

Comment: Do you need to get data from server on every page chang